# How do I reference the installed path of a file in a registry value?

Tags: wix

I want something like the following:

```
    <RegistryValue Id="Command"
                 Root="HKCR"
                 Key="myProgram\shell\open\command"
                 Type="string"
                 Value='"[SERVER_DIRECTORY]myProgram.exe" "%1"'
                 Action="write">
    </RegistryValue>
```

Where `[SERVER_DIRECTORY]` is the directory `myProgram.exe` is installed to (`ProgramFiles64Folder\MyProgram`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work the way you tried. But you can reference `myProgram.exe` as  `[#myProgram]` (meaning `myProgram` is the `Id` of a `File` element). See the [Formatted type description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609.aspx) for more details.